# How to save response.result.value from Alamofire in local array swift 3

Tags: arrays, json, swift, parsing, alamofire

```
Alamofire.request(NEWS_FEED_URL).responseJSON { response in

guard let newsResponse = response.result.value else{
        print("Error: \(response.result.error)")
        return
    }
    print("JSON: \(newsResponse)")
    let localArray:Array = [newsResponse]
    print("Local Array:", localArray)
}



I am using alamofire to fetch data from server and trying to write parser on the response data. When I fetch response.result.value from alamofire and print it is working fine. But as soon as I put response.result.value in my local array it gives  


[<__NSArrayI 0x6080000bcf80>(
{
    category = World; 
})]
```

and so on as result (Console). Also I am unable to convert response     value of type 'Any' to 'Array'. Please help me how to add     response.result.value in local array of type 'Array'. Can someone explain something about type casting on alamofire in brief?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to simply cast the result of `response.result.value` to Array of Dictionary.

```
guard let newsResponse = response.result.value as? [[String:String]] else{
    print("Error: \(response.result.error)")
    return
}
print("JSON: \(newsResponse)")
let localArray = newsResponse
//Access the localArray
print("Local Array:", localArray)
//Now to get the desired value from dictionary try like this way.
let dic = localArray[0]
let title = dic["title"] ?? "Default Title"
let link = dic["link"] as? "Default link"
//... get other value same way.
```

**Note :** Your response is already an `Array` so don't make array from it by adding it inside another array.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. But Still there is problem. As soon as I do 
guard let newsResponse = response.result.value as? [[String:Any]] else{
                print("Error: \(response.result.error)")
                return
            }
            success(true)
            print("JSON: \(newsResponse)")
It convert everything to string. And also there is array inside array there.
Output:
JSON: [["description": Washington text, "link":http://news.google.com/news/url?, "image": //t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:, "title"Washington tit
I want json formatted data in local array.

Comment: @RoshanRijal There is no problem with result it is showing perfectly swift type dictionary will be noted as `[:]` and array as `[]` so console displaying exactly the sample response that you are getting

Comment: But everything is converted to string in single array. I want my dictionaries back into that array. :)

Comment: @RoshanRijal If you access the object from array using subscript it will return you dictionary there is nothing wrong your result check `print(localArray[0])` and you will get first dictionary with its all `key:value` pair

Comment: Yes I got the first index from array and try to do this
let data = newsResponse[0]
                if let newsDict = data as Dictionary?{
                    print("newsDict:", newsDict)
                    if let title = newsDict.value(forKey:...)
                }
I am unable to fetch the data according to key..xcode is not providing me value forKey option in hint.. Did I made a mistake on converting it to dictionary?

Comment: @RoshanRijal There is no need to cast the object of array to dictionary it is already dictionary if you want to get specific key value than edit your question with actual JSON response I will edit my answer to get your value that you want

Comment: I've edited the question and provide you my actual JSON response. Did you get that?

Comment: @RoshanRijal I have edited my answer to get value from dictionary also check that I have changed array type to `[[String:String]]` from `[[String:Any]]` as of all value in dictionary are of type String.

Comment: There is still no dictionary inside local array ... Local Array: [["description": "BBC,...

Comment: @RoshanRijal It is dictionary I have already told you in Swift dictionary will be noted as `[:]`, Try once like edited answer and then you will get what you want

Comment: As you said this is working. But I've few more questions.
1) let title = dic["title"] ?? "Default Title"   let link = dic["link"] as? "Default link"  what is the meaning of ??"Default Title" and as? "Default link"...i've removed these things and it worked
2) In JSON response there are data like [{},{},{}] . Can't we fetch those datas in exact same format in local array?

Comment: @RoshanRijal I'm Saying this last time that it is dictionary and in swift dictionary is noted like `[:]`  And `??` is `Nil-Coalescing Operator` you can get more detail about it from here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html

Comment: @RoshanRijal Yes its done also as Honey suggested delete the comment that is related on accepting answer I have also deleted all comment related to it

Answer (score 1):

There is problem in `responseJOSN` result because result may not correct JSON format to correct use `[[String:Any]]` for formating JSON

```
Alamofire.request(NEWS_FEED_URL).responseJSON { response in
    guard let newsResponse = response.result.value as? [[String:Any]] else{
            print("Error: \(response.result.error)")
            return
        }
        print("JSON: \(newsResponse)")
        let firstRow = newResponse[0]
        let categoryValue = firstRow["category"] ?? "Default Category"
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Decodable technique you can save the DATA from response in user defaults. User defaults allows us to save the DATA. When you need it you can just use JSON decoder to decode the JSON Data.